Multiple InfoWindows on a Single Map
How do I display multiple InfoWindows on Google Maps? The following code only displays the first one.
  infoWindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "ABC",
    position: { lat: 38.0619833333, lng: -122.6986361111 },
    map,
  });
  infoWindow1.open(map);

  infoWindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "XYZ",
    position: { lat: 38.0, lng: -122.55 },
    map,
  });
  infoWindow2.open(map);



The above code works for me, and opens 2 info windows. However the coordinates are very close together.  If I initialize the map at zoom level 4, it's hard to see that there are 2 infowindows.  If I initialize the map at zoom level 6 or above, you can see it.
Can you add the code where you create the map as well?
